# Rails mongo query between dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have posts records that have a `created_at` date and possibly a `schedule` date.
When a post is created it can be scheduled or saved as a draft.

I want to display on a calendar all posts that were scheduled or drafted between two dates.

```
drafts = posts.where(schedule: nil).where(:created_at => post_start.to_date..post_end.to_date)
scheduled = posts.where(:schedule => post_start.to_date..post_end.to_date)
@posts = drafts + scheduled
```

This will work. But there must be a way to combine these into one query in a more efficient way. How?

Comment: `:schedule.ne => nil` is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - I was always confused about mongoid not nil. Can't find any docs on it. Anyway, since I am looking for a date range for schedule, we can rule out not nil anyway. Revised my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `or` to combine these queries.

```
posts.or(
    Post.where(schedule: nil).where(:created_at => post_start.to_date..post_end.to_date).selector,
    Post.where(:schedule.ne => nil).where(:schedule => post_start.to_date..post_end.to_date).selector
)
```